# Apple logo never lighted up!

Tags: macbook-pro

The Apple logo on my MacBook was never ever lighted up since I purchased it over a year ago. I was under the impression that some models are made this way, but on checking out how to turn it on, I'm learning that perhaps all models come with the lighted function and the common challenge lies in turning the light off. How could this be? I had placed a white Apple sticker that came with it on the cover, but now I'm feeling that I might have gotten a defective unit....what do you think?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  While are a very friendly and helpful bunch, there is an expectation that you attempt to research your question/problem and post your findings.   In this case a little research goes a long way....   First link in a [Bing search](http://www.bing.lmgtfy.com/?s=b&q=2017+macbook+pro+logo+doesn%27t+light+up)

Comment: Could you add the model number ?

Answer (score 1):

[No current model of MacBook or MacBook Pro has a logo that lights up](https://www.thrillist.com/news/nation/apple-quietly-killed-the-macbook-pros-glowing-apple-logo). Apple had to give it up in order to make thinner screens. The 13” MacBook Air is the only one left that lights up.

Comment: 2015 MBP 15" has glowing Apple logo too.

Comment: @Pratik Sure, but that’s not a current model, it’s three years old and has been superseded.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop has no light up functionality. I know this because if you can turn on your screen which I'm assuming you can the backlight would turn on and in turn light up your logo if your logo had the ability to light up.

Why would you deface a beautiful product with an apple sticker?????

The light up logo uses the same light as the backlight for the screen. I believe it was a design choice to not have the logo light up and has nothing to do with making the screen thinner.